# Product of all combinations from $1$ to $n$

Tags: combinatorics, limits

I want to calculate [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBU0S.jpg) with high school 12th grade mathematics.. is this possible? Also I'm more interested in calculating the product of all combinations from $1$ to $n$.

So basically in the photo is limit of (product of all combinations from $1$ to $n^{1/(n^2 + n)}$ as $n \to\infty $.

Comment: Hint: expand in factorial form, take the logarithm of the limit and then represent it in summation, and finally convert it to integral. The answer is $e^\frac {1}{2} $.

Comment: @민찬홍 I tried but couldn't work it out.... I get to a point after i take the logarithm something like $(n-2)/(n^2+n) * ln(n!)$ and this does not bring me to $e^{1/2}$

Comment: Expand ln (n!) to the finite sum using the definition of factorial. And the convert the limit as the limit with sum.